# How does Rotation of RelativeLayout work in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-relativelayout

I have the following relative layout (the pseudo-code of it):

```
<RelativeLayout id="container">
      <ImageView id="one" background="@color/Green"/>
      <ImageView id="two" background="@color/White"/>
      <ImageView id="three" background="@color/Yellow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So normally, there is a Green layer, a White layer on top of it and then an Yellow layer on top of that.

Currently Yellow layer is on top. Now I animate the the RelativeLayout by rotating it across Y-axis about 180 degree. Ideally what I expect it that Green layer comes on top and Yellow goes to the back. But what I get is, the RelativeLayout rotates 180 degree but the Yellow layer still stays in the front.

So, what does a rotationY in RelativeLayout does? Does it only scales it from +1 to -1, to create an effect of rotation? How can I truly rotate the layout, to achieve the case I mentioned above?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, this time to see what really happens I changed the image view to be a filled circles. Now, the Green layer has radius 30dp, White layer has radius 20dp and Yellow has radius 10dp. All have the same center. So initially, all the three filled circles are visible because of their z depth and varied radius. Ideally after the 180 rotation, only Green should be visible. But once again all three are visible.

It seems like whatever is seen prior to the 180 degree rotation is shown after the rotation (the mirror image of it). Is this what the rotationY does, show a mirror image?

**UPDATE:**

So, let's just forget about the animation. I just went ahead and set the android:rotationY="180" for the RelativeLayout in the layout itself. And I just get a mirror image. I am looking for a different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Animations (and other transformation properties) transform your view after they have been drawn. That means, your RelativeLayout draws your coloured circles based on their z-order (form api level 21 you can specify this with view.setZ(float)), which by default is the same as they appear in your xml, and then applies the transformation. That's why you still see the yellow one after rotation.

A workaround could be calling

```
greenView.bringToFront()
```

when the rotation reaches 90 degrees, to make the green one to be drawn last, thus become visible.
[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29)

Comment: I guess OP is looking for an actual rotation, as though using 3 playing cards face down and then turning them over; using `bringToFront()` will "break" the animation in that one of the playing cards will go _through_ another.